# Custom Siri Shortcut - Output a value in shortcuts app

Tags: ios, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have created a custom Siri shortcut that displays a view with some information in it. I want that information(an integer) to be accessible to other shortcuts in the shortcuts app but I can't seem to find the documentation on how to set that up

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot give any output.

Like [this Tweet](https://twitter.com/bzamayo/status/1006610427265126400) says:

> Here’s the thing about iOS 12 W̶o̶r̶k̶f̶l̶o̶w̶ Shortcuts. Workflow thrives on getting input, and passing along variables to other actions down the chain. But third-party Siri Shortcuts don’t allow for any data input or outputs.

The info dialog users see when they click the info icon of your shortcut in their shortcut app will always say *This action passes input through as output.* So you cannot customize the output.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Run Shortcut` command to pass input into a given shortcut and then receive the output of whatever said shortcut returns. For this to work, you first have to open the settings in the top right corner of the shortcut you want the other shortcuts to access. Then, you need to toggle `Show in Share Sheet`.